# Docker is failing to build in Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku

I am trying to do an auto deploy on Heroku.

I have an Heroku.yml

```
build:
  docker:
    web: packages/backend/Dockerfile
```

When it deploys I get this error

```
=== Fetching app code
=== Building web (packages/backend/Dockerfile)
=!= Dockerfile parse error line 7: Unknown flag: mount
```

This is my dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

FROM node:16-bullseye-slim

# Install sqlite3 dependencies. You can skip this if you don't use sqlite3 in the image,
# in which case you should also move better-sqlite3 to "devDependencies" in package.json.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsqlite3-dev python3 build-essential && \
    yarn config set python /usr/bin/python3
```

Any idea?

Comment: The mount is part of experimental and seems not to be supported by heroku. Did you check if it supports?